# Android SQLite Order

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

I am attempting to sort a basic database. 
I can isolate the trouble to one part: (db.query -> order -> score + "ASC"). 
The AVD and device will always crash when I execute code with the 'order' area completed. null works...but I want to sort.
I have tried modifying this code every way that I can think of..what am I doing wrong? Hope you can help, thanks

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    Button insertButton;
    EditText name;
    EditText score;

    CustomOpenHelper myOpenHelper;

    private final static String DATABASE_NAME = "SQLiteDataBasePractical.db";
    private final static int VERSION_NUMBER = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        insertButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonInsert);
        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        score = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextScore);

        myOpenHelper = new CustomOpenHelper(this, DATABASE_NAME, null, VERSION_NUMBER);

        insertButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String inputName = name.getText().toString();
                String inputScore = score.getText().toString();

                SQLiteDatabase db = myOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();

                // Wrap the database data
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put("name", inputName);
                int intScore = Integer.parseInt(inputScore); //this line converts string to integer
                values.put("score", intScore);

                db.insert(CustomOpenHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, values);

                displayDataInTable();
            }
        });

    }

    void displayDataInTable() {
        List<String> values = queryTable();

        if (values != null) {
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }

    List<String> queryTable() {
        List<String> player = new ArrayList<String>();

        SQLiteDatabase db = myOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(CustomOpenHelper.TABLE_NAME, new String[]{"_id, name, score"}, null, null, null, null, score + " ASC");

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
            int score = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("score"));
            player.add(id + " --> the player " + name + " has got a score of " + score + "s");
        }

        return player;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

As advised, Please see LogCat
`09-23 07:59:01.565    4399-4399/? I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0], There is no sepolicy file.
09-23 07:59:01.605    4399-4399/? I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_android_load_priority , spota verifySig and checkHash pass. priority version is VE=SEPF_GT-I9505_4.4.2_0046
09-23 07:59:01.605    4399-4399/? I/SELinux﹕ selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: seapp_contexts file is loaded from /data/security/spota/seapp_contexts
09-23 07:59:01.605    4399-4399/? E/dalvikvm﹕ >>>>> Normal User
09-23 07:59:01.605    4399-4399/? E/dalvikvm﹕ >>>>> com.example.eagle.sqlpracticalorder [ userId:0 | appId:10283 ]
09-23 07:59:01.605    4399-4399/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
09-23 07:59:01.715    4399-4399/com.example.eagle.sqlpracticalorder W/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ getCSCPackageItemText()
09-23 07:59:01.715    4399-4399/com.example.eagle.sqlpracticalorder I/PersonaManager﹕ getPersonaService() name persona_policy
09-23 07:59:01.795    4399-4399/com.example.eagle.sqlpracticalorder D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager
09-23 07:59:01.805    4399-4399/com.example.eagle.sqlpracticalorder D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
09-23 07:59:01.805    4399-4399/com.example.eagle.sqlpracticalorder D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
09-23 07:59:01.825    4399-4399/com.example.eagle.sqlpracticalorder D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
09-23 07:59:01.825    4399-4399/com.example.eagle.sqlpracticalorder D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
09-23 07:59:01.845    4399-4399/com.example.eagle.sqlpracticalorder D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
09-23 07:59:01.865    4399-4399/com.example.eagle.sqlpracticalorder I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:381>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (CL3869936)
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 17.01.11.SPL
    Build Date: 01/17/14 Fri
    Local Branch:
    Remote Branch:
    Local Patches:
    Reconstruct Branch:
09-23 07:59:01.925    4399-4399/com.example.eagle.sqlpracticalorder D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
09-23 07:59:01.925    4399-4399/com.example.eagle.sqlpracticalorder D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
09-23 07:59:24.797    4399-4399/com.example.eagle.sqlpracticalorder D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
09-23 07:59:24.928    4399-4399/com.example.eagle.sqlpracticalorder D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
09-23 07:59:25.308    4399-4399/com.example.eagle.sqlpracticalorder D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
09-23 07:59:28.071    4399-4399/com.example.eagle.sqlpracticalorder D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
09-23 07:59:30.443    4399-4399/com.example.eagle.sqlpracticalorder D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
09-23 07:59:30.443    4399-4399/com.example.eagle.sqlpracticalorder W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41833da0)
09-23 07:59:30.453    4399-4399/com.example.eagle.sqlpracticalorder E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.eagle.sqlpracticalorder, PID: 4399
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "{" (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT _id, name, score FROM players ORDER BY android.widget.EditText{42a92ef8 VFED..CL .F...... 0,261-1080,378 #7f0c004f app:id/editTextScore}asc
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1121)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:694)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1436)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1283)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1195)
            at com.example.eagle.sqlpracticalorder.MainActivity.queryTable(MainActivity.java:84)
            at com.example.eagle.sqlpracticalorder.MainActivity.displayDataInTable(MainActivity.java:69)
            at com.example.eagle.sqlpracticalorder.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:60)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19330)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

Comment: what is the crash ? provide us the logcat !

Comment: Please see above, I have added the entire LogCat. Please advise if it is appropriate to only add the problem section for my future reference? Best regards, Adam

Answer (score 3):

I think, you forgot whitespace here near " ASC":

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(CustomOpenHelper.TABLE_NAME, new String[]{"_id, name, score"}, null, null, null, null, score + " ASC");
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions guys. I believe you are dead right, and I have edited the code accordingly. Unfortunately, there is still another problem. I bet it has something to do with the way I have put the query together? Regards, Adam

Answer (score 0):

you need to add an empty space before asc or it will conisder it as

`"order by 15asc" //if 15 is score value` that may not be understood by SQL Engine

```
 Cursor cursor = db.query(CustomOpenHelper.TABLE_NAME, new String[]{"_id, name, score"}, null, null, null, null, score + " ASC");
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorted - Thanks for your help everyone, got some additional help from a colleague:

String[] dbArg = {"_id", "name", "score"};
        Cursor cursor = db.query(CustomOpenHelper.TABLE_NAME, dbArg , null, null, null, null, "score DESC", null);

Answer (score 0):

By look at you stack trace I saw, that you use `score` in your query. But `score` is a `TextView`, declared above. You can use something like `score.getText().toString()` here:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(CustomOpenHelper.TABLE_NAME, new String[]{"_id, name, score"}, null, null, null, null, score.getText().toString() + " ASC");
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your logcat, the answer is directly in it :

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "{" (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT _id, name, score FROM players ORDER BY android.widget.EditText{42a92ef8 VFED..CL .F...... 0,261-1080,378 #7f0c004f app:id/editTextScore}asc
```

So there is two problem :

1. As said in other answers, you miss the space between "score" and "asc"
2. `score` seems to be a variable. As we see a String representation of an object in your logcat, we can be sure that `score` is actually an EditText instead of a String.

Two solutions to handle the second point :

- if you want the value "score" (as a String) in your request, use it hard-coded (or any better way that suit your project)
- if you want to use the value set by the user in the EditText named `score`, you should use this instead : `score.getText()`